# How to handle a sync sequence in a customized Redux middleware, while the application also applied redux-saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, middleware, redux-saga

I am writing a Redux middleware for an application which adapted redux-saga as a middleware. But I cannot ensure a sync sequence in the middleware.

A saga effect function:

```
function* fetchUser(action) {
   try {
      const user = yield call(Api.fetchUser, action.payload.userId);
      yield put({type: "USER_FETCH_SUCCEEDED", user: user});
   } catch (e) {
      yield put({type: "USER_FETCH_FAILED", message: e.message});
   }
}
```

The middleware may be written like:

```
const myMiddleware = store => next => action => {
    dispatch({type: 'xxx', payload: { xxx: true }})

    next(action)

    dispatch({type: 'xxx', payload: { xxx: false }})
}
```

Fetching `Api.fetchUser` may consume several seconds, my expected sequence would be that:

```
1. dispatch({type: 'xxx', payload: { xxx: true }})
2. yield call(Api.fetchUser, action.payload.userId)
3. several seconds...
4. dispatch({type: 'xxx', payload: { xxx: false }})
```

But there is no several-seconds waiting before `dispatch({type: 'xxx', payload: { xxx: false }})`, how can I work around it?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1) Do that in a saga by itself

```js
function* whatUsedToBeTheMiddleware(action) {
 yield put({type: 'xxx', payload: { xxx: true }})
 yield call(Api.fetchUser, action.payload.userId)
 yield put({type: 'xxx', payload: { xxx: false }})
}
```

thats ensured to be one after the other.

or

2) Wait for an action in the middleware

```js
const myMiddleware = store => next => action => {
 if (action.type === 'USER_FETCH_SUCCEEDED' || action.type === 'USER_FETCH_FAILED') {
  // this is only after user fetch finishes
  dispatch({type: 'xxx', payload: { xxx: false }})
 }

 // this is always
 dispatch({type: 'xxx', payload: { xxx: true }})

 return next(action)

}
```